# Does the default zabbix SNMP trueNAS template catch disk failures?

Tags: zfs, snmp, zabbix, truenas

I understand this might be a very basic question, but I would like to know the answer to this question *before* accidentally losing all the data on the NAS due to multiple drive failures with the first going unnoticed because the pool is technically still *up* albeit *degraded*.

Does the value of this SNMP OID:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.50536.1.1.1.1.7.2
```

change whenever a disk fails? Currently the devices I'm using don't have hot-swap capability so it's a bit rough to test this. I wonder if anyone knows the answer already?

The relevant check in the template to trigger the warning appears to do this:

```
last(/truenas.mydomain.com/truenas.zpool.health[tank]) <> 0
```

What I'm wondering is if ZpoolHealth is non-zero when degraded?

Links:

- [zabbix integration into trueNAS](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/truenas)
- [FreeNAS MIB details](https://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/F/FREENAS-MIB.php)
- [OiD info for this number](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.50536.1.1.1.1.7)

Comment: Does iXSystems have any documentation about this?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20230706202507/https://www.truenas.com/docs/files/SCALE22.02Docs.pdf, page 488. 

Only info is instructions on how to enable snmp, and where to find the MIB (and a lot of places where MIB means mebibytes). The site I linked in the question makes the MIB more human readable, presents all the info in it. So I couldn't find such documentation with a cursory search.